# Piping Two Streams in Java

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

I wanted to pipe an `OutputStream` to an `InputStream` such that every time I write to my `OutputStream` those bytes become available in my `InputStream`.

Reading the JDK documentation I found the [PipeInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) and the [PipeOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) which seemed a good alternative, e.g.

```
PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(out);
```

However, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) explicitly states the two streams must be used in separate threads.

> Typically, data is read from a PipedInputStream object by one thread and data is written to the corresponding PipedOutputStream by some other thread. Attempting to use both objects from a single thread is not recommended, as it may deadlock the thread.

Is there another easy way to pipe these two streams to run in the same thread using some other features available in Java?

I suppose the major issue here is buffering the data being written by to output, since while we're writing, those bytes get buffered somewhere to be later consumed by the input reading part.

However I'm working with discrete amounts of data, of the kind that would easily fit in memory. So for me buffering a few bytes is not a big concern. I'm more interested in finding a simple pattern to do this.

Being that the case, I thought I could easily do this manually by writing everything to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then get the bytes from it and read them again in a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

However this piping scenario seems such a natural use case that I was wondering if there's another simpler way to pipe two streams in a single-threaded application, e.g.

```
output.pipe(input);
message.writeTo(output);
process(input);
```

Comment: I've run into the same problem a while ago, and I think there is some sort of circular buffer you can use.